# Directory.GetFiles Returning Duplicate File Names

Tags: .net, directory

I'm running `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("my_directory_name_on_network")` and it's just fine for most of the `11320` files in the directory, but one of them is in there twice.  Has anyone come across this before?  Any idea what it could mean?  When I look in Windows Explorer there sure appears to be just one file.

**UPDATE**

Eventually I was able to see the issue in Windows Explorer as well.  The same file name is listed there twice.

Comment: Are you sure that the extensions are the same, too ?

Comment: Oh yes.  I even did a check, and files[240] == files[241], so the strings seem to be equal.

Comment: Are you connecting to a Windows machine ?

Comment: It's some sort of file server that my NetOps department runs, I don't know its details.  When I check the properties I can see, it says Type: Network Drive, File System: NTFS, and that's about it.  Could that be relevant?  It's possible I could find out that information.

Comment: Possibly something case-sensitive?

Comment: That would make sense, but shouldn't it show up as two different file names?  Is there any way to figure out if that's the issue?

Comment: I am getting the same thing. Only one .xlsx file in the directory but it is being returned twice??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was iterating through Word documents on a local hard disk and performing some automation, not saving the files, just reading them.

I had some files that were `*.doc` and some that were `*.docx`. I used

> GetFiles("*.doc");
>
> GetFiles("*.docx");

to process all the files. However, the problem was that

> GetFiles("*.doc");

also finds `\*.docx`files so the .docx files were being found twice.

Use something like this:

```
var strFileList = Directory.GetFiles(strDrvPth, strExtn).Where(s => s.EndsWith(strExtn.Substring(1)));
```

The `Substring(1)` removes the "*" from the extension specification.